# Override default vue-formulate snow.scss theme

Tags: nuxt.js, theming, customizing, vue-formulate

English is not my native language and I might not understand the [vue-formulate documentation](https://vueformulate.com/guide/theming/customizing-classes/) correctly but I'm trying to use vue-formulate module in a Nuxt.js project. I'm importing the default snow.scss file, then my global style:

```
css: [
'@/node_modules/@braid/vue-formulate/themes/snow/snow.scss',
'@/assets/css/style.scss',
```

],

Then I try to customize class globally:

```
Vue.use(VueFormulate, {
  classes: {
    element: 'custom-element',
  },
})
```

In my style.scss I have:

```
.custom-element input:focus {
  border: 1px solid $my-color;
}
```

I can see the custom class on the wrapper around the actual  element but my style is override by `.formulate-input[data-classification="text"] input:focus` unless I add `!important`

So I wonder what I'm doing wrong here? Any help will really be appreciated! I don't want to create my own scss, the default one is a good starter where I just need to do some update and using `!important` doesn't seem to be a good practice.

Thanks in advance :)